# can't write to a new popup in javascript

Tags: javascript

I write a firefox addon.
I have the code:

```
var myWindow=window.open('','_blank','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.write("<p>lala</p>");
```

the window does created but there is nothing written to it.
why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember you have to manually *open* then *close* the document:

```
var myWindow=window.open('','_blank','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.open();
myWindow.document.write("<p>lala</p>");  
myWindow.document.close();
```